# TypeScript infer type from object keys dynamically

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, type-inference

How to create an interface to type check an object based on the keys entered in another object.

For example:

```
const myObject = {
  colors: {
    black: '#000',
    white: '#fff'
  },
  palette: {
    primary: 'black',
    secondary: 'orange' // <- should give an error because orange does not exist in colors object
  }
};
```

Comment: There is no specific interface in TypeScript which works this way.  You could take  [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wk5r9N) and represent your object type as a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), using an `asMyObject()` helper function to infer the generic type.  Does that meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing about your use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way

```
const colors = {
  black: '#000',
  white: '#fff'
};

const palette: Record<string, keyof typeof colors> = {
  primary: 'black',
  secondary: 'white'
};

const myObject = {
  colors,
  palette
};
```